# weird space behavior in vim

Tags: windows, vim, cmd, space

I'm running the Win32 console executable (v73) in Windows XP in cmd.exe and when I insert a space things get weird.

It kinda swallows a character and puts the space behind the cursor or something. For example when I write "hello there" it comes out as "helo there ".

What the hell is this?

Comment: Does this also happen in GVIM, and when launching with `vim -N -u NONE`? Do you have an insert-mode mapping: `:verbose imap <Space>`

Comment: Is the missing "l" intentional, or are you only worried about the space at the end of the string? If needed, please edit the question.

Comment: @dbenham: It is intentional. As I said, it swallows a character.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat: Doesn't happen in gvim. -N didn't do it, but -u None made the problem disappear. Now I guess I have to identify the .vim file that is causing the trouble. Is there a way to see exactly which files are sourced by vim at startup?

Answer (score 1):

When this doesn't happen with `-N -u NONE`, that means it's caused by your config or plugins.

You can check which plugins are sourced via `:scriptnames`. Often, a *binary search* where you disable half of your plugins, then only one half of that (when the problem is still there), or the other half (when the problem vanished) lets you get to the problematic script quickly.

Apart from that, look for a mapping

```
:verbose imap <Space>
```

or for relevant autocmds

```
:autocmd CursorMovedI
```